# ¿Como ocultar un bloque y mostrar en Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular

Por favor, me gustaría tener un **input** el cual al pulsar sobre el me apareciera el contenido de un **div** y que dentro tuviera un **button** que al pulsarlo desaparecia el **div** otra vez.
 **Ejemplo**

```
<div class="fileContainer">
  <input type="file">
</div>

<div>
  <p> Ejemplo </p>
  <button> Ocultar </button>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Necesitas hacerlo con angular o te vale javascript? Si necesitas angular deberías publicar también un esqueleto de tu aplicación para poder agregar el código necesario en el lugar correcto del tuyo. Mientras echa un vistazo a [https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding) y a la propiedad `[hide]`. Por ejemplo: [https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions).

Comment: también me sirve con javasrip

Comment: Es hora de salir del trabajo, no puedo seguir ahora mismo con el ejemplo de Angular. ¿Qué prefieres? ¿Angular 1.x o Angular 2? Dime la versión y te hago un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo 100% angular.

Answer (score 3):

## Solución Javascript

En javascript puedes hacer el trabajo fácilmente usando el atributo `onclick` para hacer una llamada a la siguiente función:

```
function visibilidad(selector, visible) {
  var elemento = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (elemento != null) {
    elemento.style.display = visible?'block':'none';
  }
}
```

Como parámetros puedes usar cualquier selector (sólo se modificará el primero si existen varios elementos que coincidan con el mismo selector) y el estado de visibilidad (valor que tendrá la propiedad CSS [`visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)): `true` -> `block` y `false` -> `none`.

Puedes ver más información acerca de los [selectores CSS en este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Introducci%C3%B3n/Selectors).

```js
function visibilidad(selector, visible) {
  var elemento = document.querySelector(selector);
  console.log(elemento);
  if (elemento != null) {
    elemento.style.display = visible?'block':'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#informacion {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="fileContainer">
  <input type="file">
  <button onclick="visibilidad('#informacion', true)">Mostrar</button>
</div>

<div id="informacion">
  <p> Ejemplo </p>
  <button onclick="visibilidad('#informacion', false)">Ocultar</button>
</div>
```

## Solución Angular.js 1.6

En esta otra solución hacemos uso de la propiedad [`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) para determinar cuándo debe estar oculta la capa. En nuestro caso usamos como expresión el valor de la variable `ocultar`.

Para gestionar los cambios de estado hacemos uso de [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) para cambiar el valor de `ocultar` a `false` (mostrar la capa) o `true` (volver a ocultarla) en cada uno de los botones:

```js
angular.module('pruebasApp', [])
 .controller('pruebasCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    /* El estado inicial será ocultar el contenido */
  $scope.ocultar = true;
 }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js" integrity="sha256-7ngBGhPctUEyXLD6ha53TFUaqhBCnXFOi712aqBq094=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><div ng-app="pruebasApp" ng-controller="pruebasCtrl">
  <div class="fileContainer">
  <input type="file"><br/>
  <button ng-click="ocultar = false">Mostrar</button>
</div>

<div ng-hide="ocultar">
  <p> Ejemplo </p>
  <button ng-click="ocultar = true"> Ocultar </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No es la manera correcta de hacerlo con angular

Comment: @PabloLozano lo sé, le he dado enlace a la documentación, pero le pregunté si le servía también en javascript. PD: Estoy desarrollando un ejemplo en angular, pero hacerlo que funcione aquí me lleva más tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Con angular, puedes usar `*ngIf` para mostrar o no un elemento:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="fileContainer">
        <button (click)="mostrar=true"> Mostrar </button>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="mostrar">
        <p> Ejemplo </p>
        <button (click)="mostrar=false"> Ocultar </button>
        </div>
  `,
})
class HomeComponent {
        mostrar=false;
}

const { BrowserModule } = ng.platformBrowser;

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ HomeComponent ]
})
class AppModule { }

const { platformBrowserDynamic } = ng.platformBrowserDynamic;
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

[Aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/pawer13/qe1u1kaj/) puedes verlo en funcionamiento